# Send image over socket in iPhone

Tags: iphone

How can i send image over socket in iPhone. I tried with string the code i used is as follows, now i need to send image over socket.

```
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream = NULL;

CFStringRef host = CFSTR("192.168.1.211");
UInt32 port = 8001;

CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, host, port, NULL, &writeStream);

CFWriteStreamSetProperty(writeStream, kCFStreamPropertyShouldCloseNativeSocket, kCFBooleanTrue);

if(!CFWriteStreamOpen(writeStream)) {
    NSLog(@"Error Opening Socket");
}
else{


    UInt8 buf[] = "Abc";        


    int bytesWritten = CFWriteStreamWrite(writeStream, buf, strlen((char*)buf));

    NSLog(@"Written: %d", bytesWritten);

    if (bytesWritten < 0) {
        CFStreamError error = CFWriteStreamGetError(writeStream);

    }

}
```

Regards,

Comment: You're going to need to provide a lot more detail to your question. Currently it is too broad to answer. Have you made an attempt yourself? Show the code you're trying to use.

Comment: i have added the code that i used. please help me in finding a solution

Comment: if this is not the right approach tell me the right one

Comment: You need to be more clear about what problem you're experiencing.

Comment: I need to send image(eg:.png) from iPhone to server using Socket communication

Comment: how can i convert a uiimage so that i can send the image through socket using CFWriteStreamWrite. If some one have any ideas please share.

Answer (score 1):

The image has to be converted to *base64* string and transferred through *socket*.

Here is the code snippet for base-64 conversion in Objective c

```
- (NSString *)encodeToBase64String:(UIImage *)image {
 return [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64Encoding64CharacterLineLength];
}
```

Swift

```
let strBase64:String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

Here is the [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19906825/730807)