# Sending base64 encode images over a socket

Tags: iphone, node.js, sockets

We currently are building a chat like social service, running on a node.js using sockets. the code is running fine but we have some strange behaviour when sending an encoded image(base64) over the line. it takes ages for the image to arrive around 1/2 minutes. **This is tested localhost for both the client and the server**

We can't find the issue this is the server sided code in question. the iPhone app uses the GCDAsync Library and logs everytime a write has finished. (this is almost instant) only the server is getting it a minute or two after it has been send. The image in question is 48kb

[Server Partial Source](http://pastebin.com/9iQcrvaE)

Thank you for your help. i can't seem to find the issue i hope stackoverflow can !

Comment: Whats length of your image base64 string that is created ???

Comment: Can you trace the network traffic between the two endpoints and confirm the entire file is sent immediately as you suggest it is? As an experiment, you might want to try just `POST`ing the data.

Comment: Lower your resolution of image and then convert it to base64, this could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was facing same issue while sending image via Sockets.

Like you I was sending base64 via sockets

What I Did, I resized my image to 150px x 150px and converted that into base64 and sent it to socket. Meanwhile I uploaded original image to server whose URL I added to base64 message. Now at receiver end, you need to convert base64 to image which is thumbnail, and you can either download large image in back ground or you can give user an option to download large images. This is how whats app and other messaging App works